# Suppress PHP warnings and notices in WordPress pages

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try to load WordPress, I get a lot of `Use of undefined constant ‘view’ - assumed '‘view’'` type of warnings and notices in the browser. This causes the pages to fill up with these messages before it renders the actual page content expected.

I tried changing `error_reporting = E_ALL` to `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING` but the warnings and notices still show up.

After doing `php --ini` I located both the 7.0 and 7.1 ini files and updated the value in both and restarted both FPM services on my vagrant.

- /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini

Why are these still showing up?

Comment: How 'bout fixing them problems instead…?

Comment: WordPress plays with those settings based on `WP_DEBUG` value in config...

Comment: Should be `error_reporting = 0` or `ini_set("display_errors", 0);`

Comment: Come on did you read what you wrote? *I tried changing error_reporting = E_ALL to error_reporting = **E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING** but the warnings and notices still show up.* Can you see what you changed it to. It's in plain English.

Comment: @deceze this is showing up in the WP and WooCommerce core code. I'm not interested in fixing these countless notices that WP typically allows to go thru in their code.

Comment: @eComEvo See my awnser, you can disable all notifications by setting `ini_set("display_errors", 0)`. Then all errors/warning/notifications are suppresed.

Comment: @Andreas from what I've read, changing it like that is supposed to show all errors, except for notices and coding standards warnings. Apparently the source I got this from was wrong.

Comment: Still missing an answer how to enable display for errors and at the same time disable for notices. `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` should do it as [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) says but doesn't take effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine WordPress build-in `constants` and PHP's `ini` settings.

Place these lines in your `wp-config.php`

```
ini_set('log_errors','on');
ini_set('display_errors','off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );

define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

This way all *notices*, *warnings* and *errors* will not be shown on the front-end of your website, but errors are still accesable by a log file.

Comment: These errors are in the WP and WooCommerce core code out of the box, not my code.

Comment: Yes, I know. Just set the display_errors off in your PHP.ini. The way you did it is wrong. `error_reporting` is for error reporting while `display_errors` shows the errors on the screen. By disabling that all the notifications you have will dissapear.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't do it. The warnings and notices are still showing up.

Comment: `define('WP_DEBUG', false)` combined with your suggestion fixed the issue.

Comment: Oh, yes. if `WP_DEBUG` isset to `false` it will set `display_errors` off aswell, I forgot about that :)

Comment: @Red should update the answer to specify to also make sure that the WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG constants are set to false or not declared in wp-config.php as this will override the global setting if it is. That's what fixed it for me.

Comment: @YanickGirouard Yeah, you are right. Its WordPress related, my awnser was more PHP itself related. See updated awnser.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you copied the code from some source and pasted in your file, the inverted quote ` is used instead of ', simply change the single quote and it will be fixed.

```
 change ‘view’ to 'view' and so on.
```

Answer (score 1):

To show errors and hide notices (and as was asked, warnings) there is a hacky way in **wp-config.php**:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

plus this **at the end of the file** after wp-settings.php is loaded:

```
/*hide notices and warnings*/
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING );
```

I'm saying hacky only because it's after the line saying `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */` :)